# Write $\int\limits_0^1\cos(2x)\frac{\operatorname{Ci}(2-2x)-\operatorname{Ci}(2+2x)}{x}dx$ as a series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While I was trying calculate $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x-y)\sin(x+y)}{x^2-y^2}dxdy,$$ I am wondering

> **Question.** Is it possible to write $$\int_0^1\cos(2x)\frac{\operatorname{Ci}(2-2x)-\operatorname{Ci}(2+2x)}{x}dx\tag{1}$$ as a series? Here with $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$ we are denoting the cosine integral, see the definition, if you don't know it, in this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html). **Thanks in advance.**

I try to continue to compute it, but now I don't know how get an expression of $(1)$ as a series. I know that is required to combine with the series expansion of the cosine integral and with Newton's Binomial theorem.

Comment: Hint to compute your integral, $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$

Comment: To get a series expansion perform integration by parts, an antiderivative for $1/x$ is $\ln x$

Comment: Many thanks for your notes. I take those in my notebook and I am going to thinks in these @FDP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I don't know if further simplification is possible.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and contribution. You are generous with your nice answers in this site MSE. I am going to study your nice answer.

Comment: Don't mention it. Note : Some typos in my first answer have been corrected.